# Cordova application build error

Tags: asp.net, cordova

We are getting below error while Re-build cordova application, we also tried warning message clear cache activity but still facing issue.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module **'..\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js**'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.

Comment: which version of node and cordova are you using ?

npm install -g <path-to-vs-tac>

where <path-to-vs-tac> is, probably, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac

try this one.

Comment: @Hiten still getting same issue. thanks for your feedback

Comment: Try this.
-> Close all VS instances
-> cd "%localappdata%\Microsoft\Phone Tools"
-> rename CoreCon folder
-> Launch VS again.

Comment: @Hiten We have tried both options as you have suggested.

Comment: npm install cordova -g Try this.
If not works then 
npm install taco-cli -g
npm install umask -g
npm install npmlog -g
npm install cordova -g try this and let me know is it working or not.

Comment: @Hiten thanks for your appreciated suggestion after long effort we found solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed this issue with below steps.

1. Got to--> C:\Users[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
2. Removed--> vs-tac folder
3. open command prompt and run:
   npm install -g "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac"
4. Cleaned solution with re-build